# iTunes University: Items Not Available from U.C. Berkeley

Tags: itunes

I have been listening to Professor John R. Searle's course lectures from U.C. Berkeley through iTunes University. Having finished one year's curricula, I wanted to listen another set, but, when I clicked on the link was greeted with:

[image]

macOS Sierra 10.12.3
iTunes 12.5.5.5

Looking for an explanation on Apple's Discussion forums and other Apple support sites I found little pertinent to iTunes U. - most dealing with folks uploading their own podcasts.

Is this something on my end with my apple account? (I haven't left the U.S. in ... 20 years?)

...something on Apple's end?

...something on U.C. Berkeley's end? (Maybe they only want the first years worth of lectures available in the U.S.? ...that seems weird).

Also, I get this message:

[image]

...when I click on the "get" button.

[image]

FWIW, I get an "Error - Playback Failed" on my iPhone4S (iOS9.3.5):

[image]

Is this normal? Do I just wait and keep trying? Contacting Apple via email seems likely to result in nothing but a form mail. I am nowhere near a "genius bar" and don't have Apple Care. S.O.L.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting. Turns out this is neither an issue on my end nor on Apple's.

I will post the pertinents, even if they are off-topic, because it is pretty "WTaF?"

From: http://www.weeklystandard.com/berkeley-goes-offline/article/2007201

> A few years ago, an adjunct professor and disability-rights activist named Stacy Nowak went to take a look at a college course offered online by the University of California, Berkeley. ...
>
> Since 2012, UC Berkeley (among many other schools) has offered video and audio recordings of many of its courses to the general public, via YouTube and iTunes U. The Seussian acronym is MOOCs, for massive open online courses. Over the years Berkeley's catalogue of MOOCs has grown to more than 40,000 hours of high-end pedagogy. There are introductory courses in economics, European history, statistics, physics, geography, and pretty much everything else. More advanced courses range from "Scientific Approaches to Consciousness" and "Game Theory" to "The Planets" **and "Philosophy of Language," this last taught by John Searle, the country's, and maybe the world's, greatest living philosopher.** ...
>
> After Nowak notified the National Association of the Deaf of her frustration with Berkeley's MOOCs, NAD went straight to the white-hot center of the American grievance industry, the federal government's Department of Justice. The organization filed a complaint with DoJ on behalf of Nowak and a Gallaudet colleague as "aggrieved individuals." The government lawyers got to work. ...
>
> The easiest course, administrators concluded, was simply to pull all the MOOCs from the Internet, so that disabled members of the general public will no longer have to be subjected to such discriminatory offenses—and, also, so that the federal government won't sue UC Berkeley. ...

Fortunately per: https://lbry.io/news/20000-illegal-college-lectures-rescued

> Today, the University of California at Berkeley has deleted 20,000 college lectures from its YouTube channel. Berkeley removed the videos because of a lawsuit brought by two students from another university under the Americans with Disabilities Act.
>
> We copied all 20,000 and are making them permanently available for free via LBRY.

Maybe iTunes U will pick them up, but I doubt it.